# Vectorize function with two args of different types?

Tags: julia

In Julia one can vectorize 2 arg function, when both args are of the same type:

```
function mysquare(n::Number, x::Number)
    return n * x^2
end

println(mysquare(2, 2.)) # ⇒ 8.0

@vectorize_2arg Number mysquare

println(mysquare(2, [2., 3., 4.])) # ⇒ [8.0,18.0,32.0]
```

Is there a way, aside from doing it manually, to vectorize function of two args with different types:

```
function mysquare(n::Int64, x::Float64)
    return n * x^2
end

println(mysquare(2, 2.))

@vectorize_2arg Int64 Float64 mysquare # ⇒ wrong number of args

println(mysquare(2, [2., 3., 4.]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code of [vectorize_2arg](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/operators.jl) macro. I'm not sure I fully understand all the implications here, but it works:

```
macro vectorize_2arg_full(S1,S2,f)
    S1 = esc(S1); S2 = esc(S2); f = esc(f); T1 = esc(:T1); T2 = esc(:T2)
    quote
        ($f){$T1<:$S1, $T2<:$S2}(x::($T1), y::AbstractArray{$T2}) =
            reshape([ ($f)(x, y[i]) for i=1:length(y) ], size(y))
        ($f){$T1<:$S1, $T2<:$S2}(x::AbstractArray{$T1}, y::($T2)) =
            reshape([ ($f)(x[i], y) for i=1:length(x) ], size(x))

        function ($f){$T1<:$S1, $T2<:$S2}(x::AbstractArray{$T1}, y::AbstractArray{$T2})
            shp = promote_shape(size(x),size(y))
            reshape([ ($f)(x[i], y[i]) for i=1:length(x) ], shp)
        end
    end
end

function mysquare(n::Int64, x::Float64)
    return n * x^2
end

println(mysquare(2, 2.))

@vectorize_2arg_full Int64 Float64 mysquare

println(mysquare(2, [2., 3., 4.]))
```

Can someone code-review it?

**Edit**

I [posted that on a Julia mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/aAwucZ6OQjY[1-25]): one could use

```
@vectorize_2arg Number mysquare
```

for that. No need for tweaks.

Comment: If you're looking for a code review, there's a [Stack Exchange site specifically for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). ;)